# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Tags: grails, yaml, ggts

I am using Grails 2.3.8
I am using - `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml` class.
Didn't have any issues with GGTS workspace finding the package during auto
complete in the source.
But when running the application I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

My assumption was this is part of the core Grails and the jars will be
included automatically.
Do I have to configure and add the jar or dependency in the
BuildConfig.groovy ?

Comment: Probably, have you tried that?

Comment: you have to put all your external dependencies into the `dependencies{}` block (not the `plugins{}` unless it's an plugin).  your IDE will pick that up to.

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3 uses Yaml and includes it as a dependency but prior to 3.0 it didn't, so you need to configure it like any third-party dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy`, e.g.

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.14'
}
```